# Clean way to associate/link several properties, i.e. auto update others when any of them changes?

Tags: python

For example, if one class have three properties, `x` (int), `y` (int) and `xy` (2-element list).

They satisfy: `x=xy[0]`, `y=xy[1]`. (`=` represents mathematically 'euqal'.)

**When `x` or `y` changes, auto updates `xy`, and when `xy` changes, auto updates `x` and `y`.**

I have implemented this with a really ugly way using `@property` and `@setter`.

```
class AAA:

    ...

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        if '_x' in self.__dict__:
            if self.x == val:
                return
        self._x = val
        if not '_y' in self.__dict__:
            self.xy = [val, 0]
        else:
            self.xy = [val, self.y]

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y
    @y.setter
    def y(self, val):
        if '_y' in self.__dict__:
            if self.y == val:
                return
        self._y = val
        if not '_x' in self.__dict__:
            self.xy = [0, val]
        else:
            self.xy = [self.x, val]

    @property
    def xy(self):
        return self._xy
    @xy.setter
    def xy(self, val):
        if '_xy' in self.__dict__:
            if self.xy == val:
                return
        self._xy = val
        self.x = val[0]
        self.y = val[1]
```

(Some if-else sentences are used to check existence of initial values and avoid infinite recursion of assigning same values.)

I think there must exist a more clean and general way to achieve the same goal. Say, is there any simple grammar like this:

```
x <=> xy[0]
y <=> xy[1]
```

Comment: My first approach would be to obtain `xy` from a function that takes the current values of x and y. Call that function at times when you know that x and y are updated.

Comment: @offeltoffel The case is that the priority of `xy` is the same with `x` and `y`. Your approach might ignore the case that it needs to update `x` and `y` when `xy` changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use views with a default value:

```
class AAA:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = [0, 0]  # or perhaps [None, None]

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._value[0]
    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        self._value[0] = val

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._value[1]
    @y.setter
    def x(self, val):
        self._value[1] = val

    @property
    def xy(self):
        return self._value
    @xy.setter
    def xy(self, val):
        # Assert that val is a list/tuple of two elements?
        self._value = val
```

It's pretty much the same you did, I just remove the unnecessary noise (all those ifs).

Under Python3.x you can simplify this even further with this:

```
def array_accessor(idx, getter):
    @property
    def prop(self):
        return getter(self)[idx]
    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, val):
        getter(self)[idx] = val
    return prop

def xy_accessor(idx):
    return array_accessor(idx, lambda self: self.xy)

class AAA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.xy = [0, 0]
    x = xy_accessor(0)
    y = xy_accessor(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your improvement, the trick is similar to the one used in 'swap two values correctly' with adding a third temp variable. What really makes me unsatisfied is the long codes with many `@property` and `@*.setter` -- it is so verbose. I wonder if there could be anything simple like `x<=>xy[0], y<=>xy[1]`.

Comment: I have tested your updated code and it works great like a magic! First, I have never thought that `lambda` could be used here to avoid the "'self' undefined" problem. Second, it gives `xy` property higher priority which removes infinite recursion without checking whether assigning same values. Third, the `array_accessor` function returns a decorated property, and this reduces a lot of  repeated work. Although this version is great enough and far better than my original one, is it possible to simplify it further? (Well, all programmers are greedy ...)

Comment: @Hansimov I'm not sure if further simplification is possible. I don't see it. That's all I can do for you. Perhaps someone else will come up with a better idea.

Comment: And this is why I haven't made this answer accepted: I think there must exist a simpler strategy, which might, say, skip the decorator and use a more elegant method ...

Comment: Thanks again for your great answer. It solves my problem (nearly perfectly) and I have learnt a lot from your codes!